# Почему при использование CardView фон в design резко перекрашивается в серый?

Tags: java, android, cardview

Почему при использование CardView фон в design резко перекрашивается в серый? Меняю CardView на любой другой layout и цвет становится белым. Как это исправить? (неприятно работать)
Вот код карточки`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="7dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Исправляется заданием атрибута `android:background`

```
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
```

или же можно указать свой цвет

если используются темы, то можно добавить через стили

в кардВЬю

```
style="?attr/cardViewStyle"
```

в главной теме `style.xml`:

```
<item name="cardViewStyle">@style/cardViewStyle</item>
```

и сам стиль

```
<style name="cardViewStyle">
    <item name="cardCornerRadius">@dimen/cardCornerRadius</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">@dimen/cardViewLayout_margin</item>
    <item name="cardElevation">@dimen/cardElevation</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/cardCornerRadius</item>
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/cardview_light_background</item>
</style>
```

так все будет отображаться как следует.